# Uploading app on play console with different release build algorithm

Tags: android, build, release, google-play-console

I have uploaded an application in play console with signature algorithm SHA-1 but now I want to upload the same application with algorithm SHA-256. I tried to upload the release build with algorithm SHA-256 but it gives signature error. What steps should be followed to upload app with new signature algorithm ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use SHA-1 when creating the certificate (e.g. in the keytool command line), or when signing the APK?

If the former, there's nothing you can do besides creating a new app because the certificate cannot change across the life of an app for updates to succeed on Android devices.

If the latter, then I suggest you use `apksigner` (which is what Gradle and Android Studio use) to sign your APK: it will use the best hash algorithm that works for all the devices you target. Support for SHA-256 was not always present on Android, thus depending on what minSdkVersion you set, some users may receive an APK their device is unable to verify the signature of. This also depends on the signature algorithm (e.g. RSA, DSA, etc.). All this logic is already integrated in `apksigner` so you don't have to think about which algorithm to use: it will automatically pick SHA-256 if all devices you target support it.
If you don't use `apksigner`, Play will still verify that the algorithm you signed your APK with will work on all devices from your minSdkVersion and will refuse the upload otherwise.

Hope that helps.